# Android: Programmatically generating shadows for icon with transparent background (png) and use it in a ImageButton

Tags: java, android, icons, png, shadow

Android question. How to programmatically generate an image with a shadow from a white icon with a transparent background (png)? I intend to use the image later in an ImageButton with a transparent background.